Alternative proof to $\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}(3u^2-2u^3)^n du = 2 \int_0^1 (3u^2-2u^3)^n du$

For all integer $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$, prove that the following equality holds:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}(3u^2-2u^3)^n du = 2 \int_0^1 (3u^2-2u^3)^n du
\end{align}

I am looking for elegant proofs of this equality, which is surprisingly more difficult than it seems. Here is one. Let $I =\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}(3u^2-2u^3)^n du$.
\begin{align}
 I =  \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{0}(3u^2-2u^3)^n du + \int_{0}^{1}(3u^2-2u^3)^n du + \int_{1}^{\frac{3}{2}}(3u^2-2u^3)^n du = A+B+C
\end{align}
Using the change of variables $t=3u^2-2u^3, u=x(t)$: $A= -\int_{0}^{1}t^n x'(t) dt$. Likewise, $B= \int_{0}^{1}t^n y'(t) dt$ and $C= -\int_{0}^{1}t^n z'(t) dt$, therefore:
\begin{align}
I = \int_0^1t^n [-x'(t)+y'(t)-z'(t)]dt
\end{align}
Now, $\forall t\in [0,1]$, $x(t),y(t)$ and $z(t)$ are the $3$ solutions to $-2X^3+3X^2=t$, therefore their sum is constant $(\frac{3}{2})$, and $x'(t)+y'(t)+z'(t)=0$. It follows that
\begin{align}
I = 2\int_0^1t^n y'(t)dt= 2 \int_0^1 (3u^2-2u^3)^n du
\end{align}

Then, this substitution is not a good one.

Actually, a simple study shows that the function $\phi : u \mapsto 3u^2-2u^3$ sends monotonically $[-1/2,0]$, $[0,1]$ and $[1,3/2]$ onto $[0,1]$, and we have a stronger result: for every non-negative measurable $f$ on $[0,1]$,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}f(3u^2-2u^3) du = 2 \int_0^1 f(3u^2-2u^3) du.
\end{align}
The explication is an equality of push-forward measures.
Given a piecewise strictly monotonic and $\mathcal{C}^1$ function $\varphi$ on $[a,b]$, the push-forward measure of the Lebesgue measure by $\varphi$ can be computed, using a change of variable on each interval where $f$ is strictly monotonic.
Call $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$ the restrictions of $\phi$ to $[-1/2,0]$, $[0,1]$ and $[1,3/2]$. We get
\begin{align}
\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}f(3u^2-2u^3) du = 
\int_0^1 \Big(\frac{1}{|\phi'(\phi_1^{-1}(x))|} + \frac{1}{|\phi'(\phi_2^{-1}(x))|}+\frac{1}{|\phi'(\phi_3^{-1}(x))|}\Big)f(x) dx.
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(3u^2-2u^3) du = 
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{|\phi'(\phi_2^{-1}(x))|}f(x) dx.
\end{align}
Hence, taking in account the sign of $\phi'$ on each interval $[-1/2,0]$, $[0,1]$ and $[1,3/2]$, we get
\begin{align}
2 \int_0^1 f(3u^2-2u^3) du - \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}f(3u^2-2u^3) du = \int_0^1 \Big(\frac{1}{\phi'(\phi_1^{-1}(x))} + \frac{1}{\phi'(\phi_2^{-1}(x))}+\frac{1}{\phi'(\phi_3^{-1}(x))}\Big)f(x) dx.
\end{align}
It suffices to check that for every $x \in ~]0,1[$,
$$\frac{1}{\phi'(\phi_1^{-1}(x))} + \frac{1}{\phi'(\phi_2^{-1}(x))}+\frac{1}{\phi'(\phi_3^{-1}(x))} = 0.$$
Note that the numbers $a_k := 1/\phi'(\phi_k^{-1}(x))$ are exactly the coefficients in the fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1}{\phi(u)-x} = \sum_{k \in \{1,2,3\}} \frac{a_k}{u-\phi_k^{-1}(x)}$$
and their sum is $0$ since the degree of the fraction $u \mapsto 1/(\phi(u)-x)$ is -3 < -1.

Use trigonometric substitution.
Remark. Let $u = \cos y + 1/2$. Then $6u^2 - 4u^3 = -4\cos^3 y + 3\cos y + 1 = 1 - \cos 3y$. For the three integrals, let $y = x + \pi/3$, $y = \pi - x$, and $y = x - \pi/3$, respectively.
With the substitution $u = \cos (x + \pi/3) + \frac12$, we have
$$ \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{0} (3u^2-2u^3)^n \mathrm{d} u
= \frac{1}{2^n}\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}
(1 + \cos 3x)^n \left(\frac12\sin x + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos x\right)\, \mathrm{d} x . \tag{1}$$
With the substitution $u = -\cos x + \frac12$, we have
$$\int_0^1 (3u^2-2u^3)^n \mathrm{d} u = \frac{1}{2^n}
\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3} (1 + \cos 3x)^n \sin x\, \mathrm{d} x. \tag{2}$$
With the substitution $u = \cos (x - \pi/3) + \frac12$, we have
$$ \int_1^{3/2} (3u^2-2u^3)^n \mathrm{d} u
= \frac{1}{2^n}\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}
(1 + \cos 3x)^n \left(\frac12\sin x - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos x\right)\, \mathrm{d} x . \tag{3}$$
From (1)-(3), we are done. (Note: (1) + (3), something cancels.)

Very nice. If someone asks how to come up with the substitutions, is there another answer than intuition?

@Kuifje For the cubic $3u^2 - 2u^3$, we first transform it to the form of $y^3 + py + q$, then transform to the form of $4y^3 - 3y + r$. Then use the trigonometric identity $\cos 3\theta = 4\cos^3 \theta - 3\cos \theta$. This is also the trigonometric method for cubic equation.

Transform the equality,
with $u=x+\frac12$, to an equivalent one over a symmetric range, i.e
\begin{align}
\int_{-{1}}^{1}g(3x-4x^3)dx = 2 \int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12} g(3x-4x^3) dx\tag1
\end{align}
where $g(t)= (\frac 12t+\frac12)^n$ specifically, but could be more general. Note that
$$(3x-4x^3)-(3y-4y^3)= (y-x)(4x^2+4xy+4y^2-3)$$
which motivates
the variable change $x^2+xy+y^2=\frac34$, or
$$
dx= -\frac12\bigg(1\pm\frac{\sqrt3 y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \bigg)dy 
$$
The two substitution choices are applied below respectively for $x<0$  and $x>0$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-{1}}^{-\frac12} g(3x-4x^3)dx + \int_{\frac12}^{1} g(3x-4x^3)dx\\
=&  \int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12} g(3y-4y^3) \bigg(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3 y}{2\sqrt{1-y^2}} \bigg)dy\\
&\>+  \int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12} g(3y-4y^3) \bigg(\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3 y}{2\sqrt{1-y^2}} \bigg)dy 
=\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12} g(3y-4y^3) dy
\end{align}
which leads to (1).
